# Using Postgres default values with Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm that inserts into a Postgres DB.  The DB has a timestamp that, if not specified, defaults to the current date/time.  This is what I want to happen.

Since I moved from Django form to ModelForm, the timestamp field is left blank in the DB (I assume Django fills it in as " " when the form is submitted.

How can I use ModelForm, and still have default values applied in Postgres?

Comment: `auto_now = True`, in your field maybe this is what you're looking for

Comment: @Lemayzeur - Perhaps... but I'm storing in UTC time.  Is there a UTC time equiv?

Comment: Django with `auto_now`  saves the current `datetime` based on `settings.TIME_ZONE`, so you can change your time zone to 'UTC'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `auto_now =True` to field that you want set the current datetime each time you modify the object
or
Set `auto_now_add =True` to set the current datetime only when you create the object

> more info can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now)

to have **UTC time**, in your settings, change your time zone to UTC

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Awesome!, i added a link to find more info